# How to determine the size of memory a particular load/store is accessing in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to know if load/store accesses a byte, half word, word, or double word in LLVM IR.

There is a this funtion `getAlignment()` in `llvm::LoadInst` and in `llvm:StoreInst` classes. Its description says it returns the alignment of the access that is being performed. I'm not sure if this gives the memory alignment or no of bytes it accesses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataLayout* dataLayout = new DataLayout(&module);
Value* memoryPointer = loadInstruction->getPointerOperand();
PointerType* pointerType = cast<PointerType>(memoryPointer->getType());                         
uint64_t storeSize = dataLayout->getTypeStoreSize(pointerType->getPointerElementType());
```

I have this code working on llvm-3.7. `storeSize` would be the size of the operand in bytes. Here `module` is the module pointer that you get as parameter in a module pass. The function `getPointerOperand` works for both load and store instructions. Here is the [reference](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a4b979cd93852fd44c48851c94ee00758) for function `getTypeStoreSize`. There are other functions like `getTypeStoreSizeInBits`, `getTypeAllocSize` etc which you can use as per your need.